# Promotheus: discrepancy in sum vs avg

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I have micrometer-prometheus jvm metrics monitoring configured for my spring boot application, which is deployed in kubernetes pods. There are 2 pods.

When I run query `avg(jvm_memory_max_bytes)`, I see graph hovering mostly around 400mb value. When I run `sum(jvm_memory_max_bytes)`, graph jumps up to 10gb value.

Is this much variation normal?

Answer (score 0):

The metric `jvm_memory_max_bytes` shows:

> The maximum amount of memory in bytes that can be used for memory management.

So the value will not change according to its consumption but rather on how much memory is available.

If you are trying to get how much memory has been used, you need to use the metric: `jvm_memory_used_bytes`.

You can find more information on [this page](https://tomgregory.com/spring-boot-default-metrics/), under **3. JVM Metrics**.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But if we go by this definition of sum then sum must go on increasing with timeframe as number of entries would go on increasing. But I don't see that. I selected 15 mins timeframe and 2 days timeframe. In both cases, sum shows around 10 gb.

Comment: @Mandroid You are right... I've found the reason why... I've updated my answer...